# Find the largest subarray length with delimiter

Tags: javascript, algorithm

I'm trying to solve this problem:

Given two parameters: an array `a` and integer `i`, find the largest array length where the sum of all elements is `<= i`.

For example, having the following array: `[3, 1, 2, 1]`, and `i = 4`, all the combinations that are `<= i` are: `[3], [1], [2], [3, 1], [1, 2], [1, 2, 1]`. The largest subarray is `[1, 2, 1]`, so the return of the function should be `3` (the array length).

What would be a an efficient approach to solve this problem?

This is my algorithm until now, but I know that I'm missing something:

```
function sumArray(a) {
    return a.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}

function maxLength(a, i) {
   let max = 0
   let array = [a[0]]
   a.splice(1, a.length).forEach(number => {
     array.push(number)
     if (sumArray(array) <= k) max = array.length
     else array.splice(array.indexOf(Math.max.apply(null, array)), 1)
   })
   return max
}
```

Comment: We are not doing your homework. Show what you tried that did not work.

Comment: Show what you've tried. If you're totally lost: *keep taking the smallest element out of the array, until the sum of the taken items hits your limit, or until you've taken everything*.

Comment: I added my code. I'll try what you said @CRice

Comment: I don't understand how that would work since taking the smallest element out of the array would already solve the problem of that element being <= i

Comment: This is a variation of the well-known "Maximum subarray problem".  If you search Wikipedia you'll find a useful introduction and a few possible approaches to solving it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here's how I would do it.

First, we'll get the longest sub-array by taking only the smallest elements out of the original, because that way the sum will be smallest possible as we go along. So:

```js
const original = [3, 1, 2, 1];
const maxsum = 4;

// To make sure we take only the smallest, let's just
// sort the array straight away. That way the smallest
// element will always be the first.

// The .slice call is to make a copy, so we don't change
// the original:
const sorted = original.slice().sort();

// Here's your sum function. Looks legit.
function sumArray(a) {
    return a.reduce((a, b) => a + b, 0)
}

// Now take items from the front of the sorted array and
// put them in the new array until either the original is
// empty or the max is reached.
let subarray = [];
while (sorted.length) {
    // Get the next smallest element. It's always the
    // first one because of the sort.
    const smallest = sorted.shift();
    
    // If the sum of what we have plus this new element
    // is bigger than the max, our work is done:
    if (sumArray(subarray) + smallest > maxsum) break;
    
    // Otherwise, add it to our sub array and continue.
    subarray.push(smallest)
}

// Once that loop has run, either we ran out of elements,
// or we hit the max. Either way, our job is done.
console.log("Original array:", original);
console.log("Maximal subset:", subarray);
console.log("Maximal subset length:", subarray.length);
```

Finally, if you want to get fancy, you can even do this with a single `.reduce` call:

```js
const original = [3, 1, 2, 1];
const maxsum = 4;

const maximalSubset = original.slice().sort().reduce((subset, current) => {
    if (subset.reduce((s, c) => s + c, 0) + current <= maxsum) subset.push(current);
    return subset;
}, []);

console.log("Orignal:", original);
console.log("Maximal subset:", maximalSubset);
console.log("Maximal subset length:", maximalSubset.length);
```

Although while shorter, that second snippet has the downside that we have to iterate the entire array before we get the result, whereas the first one will stop once the maximum is reached.

**EDIT:**

It turns out that the subarray needs to be a continuous piece of the original, so changing the order of the original won't work since we need to make sure the result is a continuous slice of the original.

To do that, instead, just check each subslice of the array, and keep the best one:

```js
let original = [74,659,931,273,545,879,924,710,441,166,493,43,988,504,328,730,841,613,304,170,710,158,561,934,100,279,817,336,98,827,513,268,811,634,980,150,580,822,968,673,394,337,486,746,229,92,195,358,2,154,709,945,669,491,125,197,531,904,723,667,550];
const maxsum = 22337;

function arraySum(arr) {
    return arr.reduce((p, c) => p + c, 0);
}

// Double for loop will do the trick.
let bestSoFar = [];
for (let i = 0; i < original.length; i++) {
    for (let j = i+1; j < original.length; j++) {
        if (j-i > bestSoFar.length && arraySum(original.slice(i, j)) < maxsum) {
            bestSoFar = original.slice(i, j);
        }
    }
}

console.log("Longest continuous subarray is:", bestSoFar.length);
```

Comment: is this possible without sorting the array? I think the only difference would be keeping track of the last small element added and look for the next smallest one right?

Comment: your code seems to be almost the right answer, but in one test case where it should have returned "46" it returned "49" for the array length. Here's the plunker: https://plnkr.co/edit/P2A9KMaUd2l4EPM9qbXz?p=preview

Comment: Hmm, I did notice one bug with the sort, since it's sorting by unicode order its not actually ascending. That's fixed by adding a comparator to the sort, eg: `.sort((a, b) => a - b)`. However, then the length shoots up to 51, with a sum of 22045. Can you say why you think the result should be 46 and not 51? I thought the goal was to get the longest possible?

Comment: Hmm. It occured to me that you might have additional conditions. Does the sub-array have to be a contiguous piece of the original? If so, then the result is indeed 46! I'll edit the answer to take that into consideration.

Comment: Yes, it should be contiguous block of the original array. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

A brute force approach is likely the best solution to this problem. Start at each entry and see how far you can go before arriving at a sum `> i` and if it's better than the best you've seen so far save it. I provided a sample Java solution below, I haven't actually run it so one or two of my indices may be off but I think you can get the gist. Runtime is O(n^2), memory is O(n) (both occurring with, for example, #getMaxSubArray(new int[] {1, 2, 3, 4, 5, 6, 7, 8, 9, 10}, 1000000))

```
private int[] getMaxSubArray(int[] a, int i) {
  int minIndex = 0;
  int maxIndex = -1;
  for (int j = 0; j < a.length; j+=1) {
    if (a[j] > i) {
      continue;
    }

    int sum = a[j];
    for (int k = j + 1; k < a.length; k++) {
      if (sum + a[k] > i) {
        if ((k - 1) - j > maxIndex - minIndex) {
          maxIndex = k - 1;
          minIndex = j;
        }
        break;
      }
      sum += a[k];
    }
  }

  if (maxIndex - minIndex < 0) {
    return null;
  }
  int[] result = new int[maxIndex - minIndex + 1];
  for (int p = minIndex; p <= maxIndex; p += 1) {
    result[p - minIndex] = a[p];
  }
  return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

This is my solution. It will return the max length of the subarray. Can you please take a look, guys?

```
function maxLength(a, k) {
const sortedArray = a.sort((i,j) => i - j);
let sum = 0;
let length = 0;
const subArray = [];
for (let i=0; i < sortedArray.length; i++) {
   sum = sum + sortedArray[i];
   if (sum <= k) {
      length++;
      subArray.push(sortedArray[i]);
   } else {
       return length;
   }
}
return length;
}
```